# Dial multiple numbers, hangup on non-answered and connect answered call (twilio)

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to setup a dialer system for a sales department that will dial multiple numbers from a supplied list, and await for one to be answered by a human. When this occurs, the other phones ringing should immediately be dropped.

According to [this Twilio blog post from 2009](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html), nesting  in a TwiML  command should do exactly this. However, upon my testing I find that if a single phone rejects the call no others will be dialed and the entire call-event ends. Is this no longer possible since this post in 2009, or has something changed?

I am using the twilio-client in a web interface and the node helper library to handle receiving events and generating TwiXML responses.

Comment: Are you sure **if a single phone rejects the call no others will be dialed** This one works as - _All the supplied numbers in the list are dialed simultaneously and when you reject the call from any one number, the other numbers will be dialed until the timeout attribute value_

Answer (score 4):

When you give the twiML response as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

All the numbers will be called simultaneously and If the call is rejected from any one of the numbers, the other numbers will surely be dialed out until the **timeout** attribute (in seconds) in the **Dial** verb

So you can extend this timeout as below,

```
<Dial timeout='50'>
```

[Refer](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-timeout) This documentation for more on **timeout** attribute.

In case if you again want to do some action based on the dialcallstatus,

When  ends, Twilio will submit to the action URL with the parameter
DialStatus with one of the following scenarios:

1. nobody picks up, DialStatus=no-answer
2. the line is busy, DialStatus=busy
3. the called party picked up, DialStatus=answered
4. an invalid phone number was provided, DialStatus=failed

You can handle it in the **action** attribute of **Dial** verb as below

```
<Dial timeout='50' action='your_url'>
```

So in the Response construction you can handle the other stuff based on the dialcallstatus param in the request of your mentioned "action url" from Twilio.

Comment: Really appreciate the long write up. Turns out the issue was due to having not upgraded my account off trial and dialing other numbers. I presumed using the same number would be okay, but doing so results in the behavior I described in my post. I'm sorry for taking your time, but I do appreciate it.

Comment: Yes you are right (y). But the best part is you can test this with trial plan too by verifying your numbers under the "Verified CallerId" section :) Hope this helps you for testing with multiple numbers :D

Comment: What is the DialStatus if the called party rejects the call (i.e. hangs up)? There is nothing specified on this case in the docs.

Comment: When the called party rejects the call, it is notified through the Webhook URL (REST API)
It will be "canceled", if it is done through the REST API. (As specified in the docs : https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dial-attributes)